# Тест не проходит

Tags: java, android, kotlin, espresso, android-testing

Есть вспомогательный класс `DialogIdlingResource`, благодаря которому пытаюсь запустить свои тесты, все тесты проходят за исключением этого запускается активити и доходит до шага нажатия на кнопку:

```
AcceptanceHelper.clickOnButtonInLayout(R.id.mainSignButton, R.string.common_signin_button_text, R.id.inputLayout)
```

, после чего всё замирает, хотя тест по идее должен отрабатывать(а именно проверять текст в методе isDialogRunning):

```
@Test
fun signInUserWithInvalidEmail() {
    goToSignIn()
    AcceptanceHelper.updateValidationTextView(R.string.ui_data_attribute_email, "kokojambo@mail.ru")
    AcceptanceHelper.updateValidationTextView(R.string.ui_data_attribute_password, VALID_PASSWORD)
    AcceptanceHelper.clickOnButtonInLayout(R.id.mainSignButton, R.string.common_signin_button_text, R.id.inputLayout)
    val idlingResource = DialogIdlingResource()
    registerDialogIdlingResource()
    unregisterDialogIdlingResource()
}
    private fun registerDialogIdlingResource() {
    val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
    idlingResource = DialogIdlingResource()
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource)
}


private fun unregisterDialogIdlingResource() {
    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource)
}
```

Предпологаю что ошибка из за двух методов регистрации и UNрегистрации idlingResource

Но по сути всё должно работать, но может быть где то, что скорей всего сделал ошибку, код вспомогательного класса:

```
class DialogIdlingResource(private val waitTimeSeconds: Int = 5) : IdlingResource {
private var resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback? = null
private var startTime = -1L

override fun getName(): String {
    return DialogIdlingResource::class.java.name
}

override fun isIdleNow(): Boolean {
    if (startTime < 0) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
    val timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis() - waitTimeSeconds * 1000 > startTime
    if (timeOut)
        throw TimeoutException("error")
    val idle = !isDialogRunning
    if (idle && resourceCallback != null) {
        resourceCallback!!.onTransitionToIdle()
    }
    return idle
}

override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback
}

private val isDialogRunning: Boolean
    get() {
        try {
            onView(Matchers.allOf(withId(R.id.titleTextView), ViewMatchers.withText("Warning")))
                    .check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()))
        } catch (e: NoMatchingViewException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            System.out.println("some text")
        }
        return true
    }
```

}

Comment: Добавьте метку какой фреймворк используете для тестирования.

Comment: Похоже, это вверху Java, а внизу Kotlin. Тогда в третьем фрагменте вызывается конструктор класса DialogIdlingResource. Но у DialogIdlingResource нет такого конструктора. Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: @tse в третьем фрагменте я показал как я раньше вызывал из класса java контекст(он тогда был, до замены его на id c text'ом). Теперь мне нужно точно вызвать их, из  класса java как я вызывал раннее контекст

Comment: Id чего  и text чего ты хочешь получить?

Comment: @tse в конструкторе у меня есть значения id и text
их я хочу получить в моём @ Before после instrumentation...

Comment: Не, не понимаю. Они есть в конструкторе DialogIdlingResource, и тебе надо из instrumentation получить эти id и text, чтобы создать DialogIdlingResource? Или с их помощью уже был создан DialogIdlingResource, который надо получить из instrumentation, чтобы получить эти id и text?

Comment: @tse обновил вопрос, с некоторыми обновлениями, надеюсь сейчас будет более понятен вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу скажу у Вас слишком замудренная реализация того, что можно сделать гораздо проще, ну как мне кажется. На данный момент я вижу два варианта:

Первый вариант подробно описан по ссылке в данной репозитории  [github](https://gist.github.com/vaughandroid/e2fda716c7cf6853fa79).
Принцип которого заключается в проставлении необходимых Вам параметров и место где они распологаются. Также советую обратить внимание на флаги параметра visibility.

Ну а второй вариант будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом. Создаём класс, который унаследуем от `IdlingResource`, имплементируем его методы и заполняем:

```
class ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(private val activity: SignActivity?) : IdlingResource {
private var callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback? = null

override fun getName(): String {
    return "SignInScreenTest"
}

override fun isIdleNow(): Boolean {
    val idle = isIdle
    if (idle) callback!!.onTransitionToIdle()
    return idle
}

val isIdle: Boolean
    get() = activity != null && callback != null

override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
    this.callback = resourceCallback
}
}
```

После этого в Ваших тестах после нажатия на кнопку реализуем вызов следующим образом:

```
val activity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity()
val idlingResource = ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(activity)
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource)
```

Где мы "получаем" компоненты нашей аквтивности, иначе открытые элементы/переходы возможно приведут к `null` вашей активити. Как я понял, Вы пытыетесь открыть в Вашей `activity` диалог. После чего регистируем наши `idlingResource` из класса. После того как открылся Ваш диалог например, Вы можете проверить элементы содержащиеся в нём, или просто вернуться назад. После всех операций, в этом же тесте нужно вызвать:

```
Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource)
```

Также Вы наверное видели уже что возможно поместить методы `registerIdlingResource/unregisterIdlingResources` в аннотации @Before/@After чтобы не прописывать всегда одно и то же, если тестов скажем несколько.

И опять же для дополнительного чтения : [пример использования](http://matgom.com/tutorial/2016/02/21/IdlingResource.html).

Comment: Спасибо, в целом получилось, и когда запускаю данный тест отдельно, то всё хорошо, но если же запускаю всё целиком, то диалог не успевает загрузиться и соответственно тест падает, но если я проставляю после `Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource)` таймаут - `        onView(isRoot()).perform(AcceptanceHelper.waitFor(10000))` то тогда всё работает корректно, но по-моему теряется весь смысл данной реализации, так как он всё равно ожидает 10 секунд.

Comment: Ну если Вы ожидаете диалог, то соотвественно вам нужно в классе 'ElapsedTimeIdlingResource' проверять его, а не activity. Или Вы так и сделали?